# deadline picker for post swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have text Feld and I post text
and I need it to be in deadline
now when I post it will be post not wait to the time then post
I hope you understand me .
SO what I should do?

this was the code I wrote

```
import Foundation
struct TodoItem {
    var title: String
    var deadline: Date
    var UUID: String

    init(deadline: Date, title: String, UUID: String) {
        self.deadline = deadline
        self.title = title
        self.UUID = UUID
    }

    var isOverdue: Bool {
        return (Date().compare(self.deadline) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending) // deadline is earlier than current date
    }
}
```

2-this is next code i add it all to under stand my vision 
so this is to post go next view and more

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TodoList {
    class var sharedInstance : TodoList {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: TodoList = TodoList()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    fileprivate let ITEMS_KEY = "todoItems"

    func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
        let todoDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:]
        let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)
        return items.map({
            let item = $0 as! [String:AnyObject]
            return TodoItem(deadline: item["deadline"] as! Date, title: item["title"] as! String, UUID: item["UUID"] as! String!)
        }).sorted(by: {(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
            (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .orderedAscending)
        })
    }

    func addItem(_ item: TodoItem) {
        // persist a representation of this todo item in NSUserDefaults
        var todoDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: ITEMS_KEY) ?? Dictionary() // if todoItems hasn't been set in user defaults, initialize todoDictionary to an empty dictionary using nil-coalescing operator (??)
        todoDictionary[item.UUID] = ["deadline": item.deadline, "title": item.title, "UUID": item.UUID] // store NSData representation of todo item in dictionary with UUID as key
        UserDefaults.standard.set(todoDictionary, forKey: ITEMS_KEY) // save/overwrite todo item list

        // create a corresponding local notification
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Todo Item \"\(item.title)\" Is Overdue" // text that will be displayed in the notification
        notification.alertAction = "open" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
        notification.fireDate = item.deadline as Date // todo item due date (when notification will be fired)
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
        notification.userInfo = ["title": item.title, "UUID": item.UUID] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later

        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)



        var inputValue = [index]

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.alhumaidi.net/hamsat1.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "&b=\(item.title)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")};

        task.resume()

    }


    func removeItem(_ item: TodoItem) {
        let scheduledNotifications: [UILocalNotification]? = UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications
        guard scheduledNotifications != nil else {return} // Nothing to remove, so return

        for notification in scheduledNotifications! { // loop through notifications...
            if (notification.userInfo!["UUID"] as! String == item.UUID) { // ...and cancel the notification that corresponds to this TodoItem instance (matched by UUID)
                UIApplication.shared.cancelLocalNotification(notification) // there should be a maximum of one match on UUID
                break
            }
        }

        if var todoItems = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: ITEMS_KEY) {
            todoItems.removeValue(forKey: item.UUID)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(todoItems, forKey: ITEMS_KEY) // save/overwrite todo item list
        }
    }
}
```

now when I add new post it go to next view but it post not wait the time to post.

3-

```
import UIKit

class TodoSchedulingViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var deadlinePicker: UIDatePicker!



    @IBOutlet var info: UITextField!

    var inputValue = [index]


    @IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let todoItem = TodoItem(deadline: deadlinePicker.date, title: info.text!, UUID: UUID().uuidString)
        TodoList.sharedInstance.addItem(todoItem) // schedule a local notification to persist this item
        let _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) // return to list view




        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.xxxxx.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "&b=\(info.text!)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")};

        task.resume()

    }

}
```

4-

```
import UIKit

class TodoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var todoItems: [TodoItem] = []




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TodoTableViewController.refreshList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TodoListShouldRefresh"), object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        refreshList()
    }

    func refreshList() {
        todoItems = TodoList.sharedInstance.allItems()
        if (todoItems.count >= 64) {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.isEnabled = false // disable 'add' button
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return todoItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "todoCell", for: indexPath) // retrieve the prototype cell (subtitle style)
        let todoItem = todoItems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as TodoItem

        cell.textLabel?.text = todoItem.title as String!
        if (todoItem.isOverdue) { // the current time is later than the to-do item's deadline
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black // we need to reset this because a cell with red subtitle may be returned by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath:
        }

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'Due' MMM dd 'at' h:mm a" // example: "Due Jan 01 at 12:00 PM"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: todoItem.deadline as Date)

        return cell


    }






    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true // all cells are editable
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete { // the only editing style we'll support
            // Delete the row from the data source
            let item = todoItems.remove(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) // remove TodoItem from notifications array, assign removed item to 'item'
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            TodoList.sharedInstance.removeItem(item) // delete backing property list entry and unschedule local notification (if it still exists)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.isEnabled = true // we definitely have under 64 notifications scheduled now, make sure 'add' button is enabled
        }




    }
}
```

than you all.

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMKXW.png)

Comment: I’m sorry, I can’t see what the question is. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: @Abizern Hi
thank you
what i want is when i add text it wait until coming the time i chose it .